# How to exclude usernames in search queries in Twint module

Tags: python, data-science, twint

```
import os
import twint
import nest_asyncio
import pandas

nest_asyncio.apply()

c = twint.Config()
SearchString = "(covid19 OR covid OR covid-19) until:2020-01-01 since:2019-12-01)"
c.Search = SearchString
c.Lang = "en"
c.Pandas = True

twint.run.Search(c)
```

Here I only want tweets that have those following words, but I also get tweets from usernames having words from my search query.

How should I search for those tweets at the same time exclude usernames with those words?

Answer (score 1):

To exclude searches of a particular keyword in twint you can use -keyword. This works for excluding usernames too.

for instance, to exclude orange from the query.

C.search('apple OR -orange').

and I suggest you to search using #. It will give you a better result like #covid #covid-19. That way you will not end up getting same username and keyword.